# Next.js Prerender Error "Cannot read properties of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I am using Next.js to create a React application (full code can be found [here](https://github.com/spencer-shadley/workout-tracker-base).)

I'm hitting an odd error that's difficult to debug. When running `next build` I get the below errors complaining about prerendering, one error for each of my five pages:

```
spenc@WhiteBoxu:~/workout-tracker$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /home/spenc/workout-tracker/.env.local
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/5)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/StartWorkoutPage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/ActiveWorkoutPage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at exports.useEffect (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:292)
    at QueryClientProvider (file:///home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:46:9)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
info  - Generating static pages (5/5)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
        /ActiveWorkoutPage
        /StartWorkoutPage
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
```

What's weird to me is:

1. This works when running `yarn build` (which maps to just `next build`)
2. `yarn dev` also works (guessing there's no pre-rendering for local dev so that would make sense)
3. It complains specifically about `QueryClientProvider` from `@tanstack/react-query` but if I delete this and make `_app.tsx` just directly return `<h1>foo</h1>` it instead produces this similar error:

```
spenc@WhiteBoxu:~/workout-tracker$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /home/spenc/workout-tracker/.env.local
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/5)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at exports.useState (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:394)
    at CreateWorkout (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/pages/StartWorkoutPage.js:33:88)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at useRouter (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/chunks/620.js:710:35)
    at WithRouterWrapper (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/chunks/620.js:1108:43)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)

Error occurred prerendering page "/StartWorkoutPage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at exports.useState (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:394)
    at CreateWorkout (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/pages/StartWorkoutPage.js:33:88)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at exports.useState (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:394)
    at Steps (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/pages/index.js:247:69)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at exports.useState (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:394)
    at Steps (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/pages/index.js:247:69)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/ActiveWorkoutPage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at useRouter (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/chunks/620.js:710:35)
    at WithRouterWrapper (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/chunks/620.js:1108:43)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/home/spenc/workout-tracker/.next/server/pages/_error.js:283:44)
    at Wc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/home/spenc/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
...
```

Here is my `_app.tsx`:

```
import '@/styles/globals.css';

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';

import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);

import BackgroundWaves from '@/components/shared/BackgroundWaves';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <BackgroundWaves />
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

and my `package.json`'s `scripts`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "heroku": "yarn build && heroku local",
    "check-types": "tsc --noemit",
    "lint": "npm run check-types && next lint"
  },
```

I checked https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error but wasn't able to find anything that stuck out from

It seems like there might be some infrastructural issue? Any advice on either what's going on and/or how to debug something like this?

Comment: you said it builds with `yarn` but not with `npm`. is this correct?

Comment: Correct. 

yarn build - success |
npm run build - success |
next build - failure |

I'm confused why these three commands are not equivalent and how to fix next build

Comment: I tried with ‘yarn build’ it gave me same error

Comment: This is what `yarn build` gives me

spenc@WhiteBoxu:~/workout-tracker$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next build
...
info  - Compiled successfully
...
info  - Finalizing page optimization  
...
├ ○ /ActiveWorkoutPage                     12.4 kB         146 kB
└ ○ /StartWorkoutPage (3458 ms)            37.4 kB         182 kB
...

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

Done in 13.88s.

Comment: It requires an API key for OpenAI to be set in .env.local - I'm not sure what errors you'll get without that

Comment: Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Answer (score -1):

I just experienced something similar but it was with my product routes
`/product/[slug]`.  I moved the directory to a new `/pageStash` directory, essentially just hiding it from the build.  The deploy worked.  So I "unstashed" the `/products/[slug]` directory ( placing it back into the `/pages/` dir ) and the build worked.  WHY??  Who knows....